# Show different layouts in fragmentation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem that I want to load different layouts every time in a fragment when a list Item is clicked from different fragment. Means I have two fragments on a screen, first one is ListView and on another I want to show different layouts according to clicked item from list view means If I clicked on About Us item then the Details pane shows the layout of About Us and If clicked on Contact Us the Details Pane will changed to accordingly. Currently a layout is showing images which is created at run time. Please suggest me for the right result.

**My Main Activity:**

```
public class FragmentTestActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.number_list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> numbers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                new String [] {
            "About US", "Contact Us", "Services", "four", "five", "six"
        });
        l.setAdapter(numbers);
        l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Add a Fragment to our stack with n Androids in it
     */
    private void stackAFragment(int nAndroids) {
        Fragment f = new TestFragment(nAndroids);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.the_frag, f);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Called when a number gets clicked
     */
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        stackAFragment(position);
    }
}
```

**Details Pane Area:**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private int nAndroids;

    public TestFragment() {

    }

   /**
    * Constructor for being created explicitly
    */
   public TestFragment(int nAndroids) {
        this.nAndroids = nAndroids;
    }

    /**
     * If we are being created with saved state, restore our state
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        super.onCreate(saved);
        if (null != saved) {
            nAndroids = saved.getInt("nAndroids");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save the number of Androids to be displayed
     */
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle toSave) {
        toSave.putInt("nAndroids", nAndroids);
    }

    /**
     * Make a grid and fill it with n Androids
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saved) {
        int n;

        Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(c);

        for (n = 0; n < nAndroids; n++) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(c);
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
            l.addView(i);
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off (cleaner design) if you used separate `Fragments` for the different data types you are presenting.  This will keep your `Fragments` cleaner and the `Activity` can just create the appropriate `Fragment` and replace the previous one in the container view.  However, if you *really* want to do it the way you describe, you can pass a "mode" to the `Fragment` via its argument `Bundle` and the `Fragment` can use that information to inflate the appropriate layout file and logic.

See this developer guide for details and examples with using arguments and fragments: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html