# Android 3.0 fragment:creating different views in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

created sample app of fragment from http://www.kaloer.com/making-your-app-tablet-friendly-3-steps#comment-495 .how to load different views in Detail page with respect to list items in listFragment
found similar question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712323/show-different-layouts-in-fragmentation) but unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this code as according to related your parameter in onclick method or what ever you use like Onitemclick etc..

```
        Fragment f = listFragment(listid);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_tasklist_layout, f);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: Hai Steve I have tried that but not working.
 want to load different layouts in Detail page when list item clicked eg- first item loads layout_1.xml second loads latout_2.xml

Comment: For that you have to create separated xml file and java file with extends Fragment for each layout and put this line in onCreateView method "View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_task, container, false);" and return v in the method.

to get the view is like "LinearLayout lv1 = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.add_edit_list);"

Comment: Thanks Steve, added layouts for each list item

Comment: If it Works and helpful to you than accept the answer so other can get the solution and be helpful to others also.